# Tips on writing a Forumsbeitrag for Goethe Zertifikat B2 Prüfung

Tags: grammatical-case, writing, proficiency-test

I am sometimes a bit confused due to the Inhaltspunkte:
For example,

- Äußern Sie Ihre Meinung zu fleischreicher Ernährung im Alltag.
- Nennen Sie Gründe, warum eine Ernährung mit Fleisch so verbreitet ist.
- Nennen Sie andere Möglichkeiten, sich zu ernähren.
- Nennen Sie Vorteile anderer Ernährung.

From written examples online, I find that die Äußerung der Meinung is always combined with die Nennung der Gründe, it makes me a bit worried, if I can get full marks this way, or should I do the seperately?

Comment: Can you give an example of what a combination or a separate statement would be? You're supposed to author one single piece of writing, so necessarily they will be "combined" in some way.

Comment: Are you sure that you fully understood the topics? The second topic doesn't ask about reasons for your opinion as asked in the first one. (Of course you can combine your opinion with reasons.) The second topic merely asks for reasons why meat-rich diet *is so widespread*. In my opinion, this is different from the reasons that may be part of the first topic.

Comment: I agree with Bodo. I dont know what exactly is expected (I guess that had been discussed at some point), but I would state my opinion in 1) and maybe, although it doesnt say "und begründen Sie Ihre Meinung", add a small paragraph ala "my opinion is based on..." and then answer 2-4 objectively.

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider them to be distinct topics but rather a guideline of things that should be covered in this exam, since it's one base topic. They can easily overlap, but this is no bad thing, when done properly, it's not just blocks of text but one arc that covers all aspects of nourishment.

So I would not worry about said overlap, make sure the topic is covered to the extent you feel is adequate, then see if it takes you to the next topic, just don't force it.

Covering your final concern, Äußerung der Meinung & Nennung der Gründe usually would be close together, but their specifications make the pull apart a bit:

- the opinion is in regard to meat-rich nutrition
- the reasons concern the fact the eating meat is widely spread among people

This can be related, but doesn't have to be, so it could be covered as just two loosely related topics.